# Scrollable horizontal ul without overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list like that

```
<ul class="pagination">
   <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#!" rel="1">1</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="2">2</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="3">3</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="4">4</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="5">5</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="6">6</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="7">7</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

If my list is too long, instead of using two 'lines' to display I replace some items by '...' and I hide some other. I'd like to be able to scroll on the ul element. But if I set

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

I have the scrollbar but I can't scroll on this element because there is enough place to display all the items displayed.

The goal is that when I scroll on the ul element I can show some other elements which are hiding.

**Example :**

```
<ul class="pagination">
   <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#!" rel="1">1</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="2">2</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect" style="display: none;"><a href="#!" rel="3">3</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect" style="display: none;"><a href="#!" rel="4">4</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="5">...</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect" style="display: none;"><a href="#!" rel="6">6</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="7">7</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

**JSFiddle : **
https://jsfiddle.net/10am4rqh/

Comment: Can you please create example so we can see issue in action.

Comment: don't use `scroll` that means the bar is always present, try using `auto`

Answer (score 0):

here hope this helps...

```css
.pagination {
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-height: 35px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
   <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#!" rel="1">1</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="2">2</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="3">3</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="4">4</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="5">5</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="6">6</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="7">7</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow: auto` so scrollbar will only appear when content is bigger than parent element.

```css
.pagination {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
   <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#!" rel="1">1</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="2">2</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="3">3</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="4">4</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="5">5</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="6">6</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!" rel="7">7</a></li>
   <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
</ul>
```